# Django 1.5 NoReverseMatch at /blog/

Tags: django

In Django 1.5 I have my pages to working nicely until i try to use {% url %} to display a link. I have read some Django docs and looked through Stack Overflow but I can't get my item to work.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

**Error I Get**

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'single' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', blog, name = 'blog'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>(\d+))/$', single, name = 'single')
)
```

**blog.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'single' o.id %}">Read More</a>
```

**SOLUTION**

**SOLUTION**

**SOLUTION**

It's that stupid semicolon!

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:single' o.id %}">Read More</a> 

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', blog, name = 'blog'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', single, name = 'single')   
)
```

Comment: Have you tried without brackets?: `url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', single, name = 'single')` ?

Comment: And for `{% url 'blog' %}` it works?

Comment: None of them work, and this doesn't Work:
   `url(r'^$', blog, name = 'blog')`
and `<a href="{% url 'blog.blog' %}">Read More</a>`

Comment: `<a href="{% url 'single' o.id %}">Read More</a>` gives me `Reverse for 'single' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', single, name='single')
    url(r'^$', blog, name='blog')
)
```

You don't need parenthesis around the pattern `\d+` in this case.