# Why am I getting NoReverseMatch at /blog/ in Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently following the book "Django by Example" and at chapter 1: Building a blog application, I am getting the following error when I try to access 127.0.0.1:8000/blog/

> NoReverseMatch at /blog/
>
> Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '(2017, '08', '03',
>   'new-title')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried:
>   ['blog/(?P\d{4})/(?P\d{2})/(?P\d{2})/^(?P[-\w]+)
>   /$']

Here is my templates/blog/base.html file

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <div id = "sidebar">
    <h2> My Blog</h2>
      <p> This is my blog </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my templates/blog/post/list.html file

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1> My Blog </h1>
  {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="date">
      Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>

    {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I cannot seem to find what is wrong, so I would appreciate your assistance.

In case it helps, I am using Django 1.8.6 and Python 3.6.2 with virtualenvwrapper on a Linux system.

Comment: please show your views.py and urls.py and models.py with post model

Comment: check this question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417455/django-1-5-noreversematch-at-blog hope you get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two errors in your regex.

Firstly, you have a stray `^` before the final pattern. That means "match from the beginning of the string", so putting it in the middle of the string will always fail.

Secondly, you have a space before the final slash.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is a reverse url for "post_detail". You need to have a url that has name with the value "post_detail".

Add this to urls.py

```
url(r'^blog/(?P\d{4})/(?P\d{2})/(?P\d{2})/^(?P[-\w]+) /$'', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

your view should also accept regular expression like;

```
def post_detail(request, pattern):
    ....
    return render(request, template, context)
```